# Помогите с вызовами функций. Python

Tags: python, функции

```
import time

obychenie = print('Обучение: После любых вопросов, Вы должны написать: A, B, C, D, Y, N, a, b, c, d, y, n. Ещё вариантов ответа ответа может быть не четыре а допустим три. Ещё если вы напишите что-то другое, игра будет завершена!')
inp = input('Вы хотите продолжить?(y/n): ')

def dtxt():
    txt = print('\n   Вы снова попали в имперскую тюрьму за карманую кражу. Обычно когда Вы отсидели месяц за такое, и Вас отпускали.')
    txt2 = print('Но на этот раз что-то не так, и Вы продолжаете сидеть в этом гнилом месте.')
    txt3 = print('Напротив вашей камеры, стоит заключённый. Он смотрит на Вас как обычно, как-то косо. Всё потому что Вы уже не первый, не второй и даже не третий раз здесь находитесь.')
    txt4 = print('Вы даже знаете что он сидит за попытку убить Императора. Хотя обычно за такое казнь, но его посадили просто пожизненно!')
    txt5 = print('А вот имени его Вы не знаете. Наверное потому что никогда в голову не приходило спросить. Хотя даже не логично немного, сидите не первый раз по месяцу и не знаете имени человека напротив')
    txt6 = print('Что по охране? Иногда проходит мимо камер и смотрит чтобы всё было впорядке.')
    txt7 = print('Как раз когда будет проходить, спрошу что на счёт меня?')
    txt8 = print('А сейчас нужно решить, ждать охрану или поговорить c заключённым...')
    txt9 = print('\n------------------------------------------------------------------------\n')

def ifelse():    
    if inp == 'y' or 'Y':
        dtxt()
    else:
        quit
ifelse()

def a1():
    print('A: Подойти к заключённому')
    print('B: Ждать охрану.')

def a2():
    return input('Выберите ответ: ')

def a6():
    print('\nA: Сказать: "Ты слышал о чём они говорили?"')
    print('B: Сказать: "Как-то не верится."')
    print('C: Ничего не делать и ждать охрану.')

def a5():
    return input('\nВыберите ответ: ')

def a3():
    print('Вы подошли к заключённому.')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('\nЗаключённый:\n"Не надоело ещё?"')
    print('"Кстати! Пока тебя ещё не привели, я слышал как охрана о тебе говорила. Похоже что ты тут уже не на месяц."\n')
    time.sleep(1)
    a6()

def a4():
    print('Вы ждёте охрану.')

def a7():
    print('Заключённый: "Тихо! Кто-то идёт."')

def a8():
    print('Похоже кто-то идёт.')

def a9():
    print('Ладно, пойду прилягу.')

answer = a1()
answer = a2()
if answer == 'a':
    a3()
elif answer == 'b':
    a4()
else:
    quit


answer = a5()
if answer == 'a':
    a7()
elif answer == 'b':
    a8()
elif answer == 'c':
    a9()
else:
    quit
```

Когда сценарий доходит до функции `a1` и `a2`, я пишу ответ `a` или `b`. Когда пишу `а`, то всё идёт по сценарию. А когда написал `b`, то всё идёт тоже по сценарию но ещё в добавок пишет функцию `a5`. Как предотвратить вывод `a5`?

Comment: a5() вызывается вне зависимости от предыдущего ответа. Но тут проще всего переделать всё нормально. Нечасто увидишь у начинающих такие спагетти

Answer (score 0):

Что такое "quit"? Может нужно так?

```
quit()
```

или так

```
sys.exit(0)
```